# Draw boxplot seaborn without groups

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn

I want to draw boxplot in seaborn (not matplotlib), but it gives me an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

I didn't find anything like my data on online documentation or other tutorials. My data looks so simple it is just a bunch of observation:
e.g

```
  1.       2.     ...     ... 
1.010.   2.343.   ...
2.030.   2.534.   ...
2.433.   2.748.   ...
1.933.   2.432.   ...
  ...     ...
```

I converted my data to pandas.DataFrame and it looks like what I wrote above (number of observation is the first string(pandas.columns) and values are below). It doesn't work **sns.boxplot(data)**. May be there are some arguments or something else. Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A boxplot needs a list of list of numbers to plot, or if it is a dataframe it will plot each column as a boxplot, but each column needs to have the same length of data. Try converting your series to a list and plotting like so:

```
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(ax=ax, data = data_df_series.tolist())
```

If this doesnt work, what is the data type of your series? Try doing:

```
df.dtype
```

Additonally, are there any NaN values?

Also, you do not need to convert your data to a pandas dataframe, as it will just be converted to a list before being plotted beforehand. If it is not already a pandas dataframe, you can keep it as whatever it was before (i.e. a list or a numpy array)

Comment: I've done something because of you :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using seaborn 0.11.1, you can directly call `sns.boxplot`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1.010, 2.030, 2.433, 1.933], 
                   '2': [ 2.343, 2.534, 2.748, 2.432]})
sns.boxplot(data=df)
```

[image: boxplot from simple dataframe]